# How to set the breakpoint() to launch IPython shell? (Python 3.7+)

Tags: python

The python 3.7+ breakpoint()-function launches the python debugger by default. How can I make it to lauch the IPython shell* instead?

*By IPython shell I mean the `embed()` -function from `IPython` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` environment variable to point to the relevant function from the IPython package. See [PEP 553 -- Built-in breakpoint()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/) for more details.

Comment: Yes! It seems that setting the `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` to `IPython.embed` works well!